# Can I use the battery from an early 2014 MacBook Air in a mid 2012 Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

I just bought a used mid-2012 MacBook Air to replace the early-2014 model my dog killed but the battery life is terrible comparatively.

Can I take the battery out of the 2014 and use it in the 2012 safely?

Comment: Have a go hopefully it should work.

Comment: @RACING121 Yeah, it's worth a try. Apple products are funny about stuff like that. One I was repairing a CDMA iPhone 4 by replacing the dock connector, but the place where I bought replacement parts sold me a dock connector for an iPhone 4s by mistake. Surprisingly, though it didn't fit inside the phone right, it worked just fine. However, I don't know how it worked in the long run, because the seller switched out the part for a proper one. Anyways, that battery shouldn't harm you or your MacBook, but you can compare the specs of them anyways.

Comment: @RedEagle2000 Apple... ;)

Comment: I'd contact Apple to be sure however from what I looked at on the Internet at several sites that offer parts and in particular the battery they are not the same between those years.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. According to iFixit, all 2010 through 2017 MacBook Air's use the same battery:

https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Late-2010-to-2017-Replacement-Battery/IF188-113-2

That's assuming we are talking about the 13". If you are talking about an 11", that changes things.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **YES**

Apple is going to use different part numbers but essentially they are the same battery.

The easiest way to see if the batteries are interchangeable is to take a look at the aftermarket battery replacement.  For example, this particular battery made by [GreenBox Innovations and found on Amazon](http://amzn.to/1X5MHMh) fits Macbook Air Models from Late 2010 through Early 2014

[image]